# How to get a model by id when injecting a model to a controller?

Tags: php, laravel

```
class LessonController extends \BaseController {

  protected $lesson;

  public function __construct(\Lesson $lesson)
  {

  }

  public function edit($lesson)
  {
    var_dump($this->lesson);
  }

}
```

Here how can I var_dump the selected model based on the user going to a route like `domain.com/lesson/edit/{id}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're injecting isn't an instance of the model, but rather the class that provides access to instances.  Your calls will look like un-injected calls but with $this->lesson replacing Lesson::.

To find a particular instance, then, you'll call

```
$lessonInstance = $this->lesson->find($id); // if not injected, would be Lesson::find($id)
var_dump($lessonInstance);
```